# Changing background color and font in vtable::sumtable

Tags: r, vtable

I've created a descriptive data table with sumtable(), but it displays grey and white rows as below. I'd like it to be all white, and change the font.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `sumtable` generates an html output with fixed characteristics. If you want to style it yourself, you have the option to pass it to `kable`, and set all the parameters you want via `kable_styling()`:

```r
library(vtable)

sumtable(mtcars, out = 'kable') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(html_font = 'Comic Sans MS')
```

[image]